# how to exend nodejs class to add new static class elements

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question in which I suspect extending a class is the answer, but I am not certain. Here is the situation... There is a class like this:

```
class Field {

    apiName;
    /**
     * Creates an instance of Field with the given parameters
     * @param {String} apiName A String representing the apiName
     */
    constructor(apiName){
        if((apiName != null) && (!(Object.prototype.toString.call(apiName) == "[object String]")))  {
            throw new SDKException(Constants.DATA_TYPE_ERROR, "KEY: apiName EXPECTED TYPE: String", null, null);
        }
        this.apiName = apiName;

    }

    /**
     * The method to get the apiName
     * @returns {String} A String representing the apiName
     */
    getAPIName()    {
        return this.apiName;

    }
    
    static Contacts = class {
        static FIRST_NAME = new Field("First_Name");
        static LAST_NAME = new Field("Last_Name");
        static LEAD_SOURCE = new Field("Lead_Source");
        static EMAIL = new Field("Email");
        ...

    }
}

module.exports = {
    MasterModel : Field,
    Field : Field
}
```

In my application code, I have a module that looks like this (with a lot for detail removed for clarity)

```
const RecordField          = require(`${SDK_API}/record/field`).Field;
const ZCRMRecord           = require(`${SDK_API}/record/record`).MasterModel;

const updateRecord = async(query) => {

    const record = new ZCRMRecord();
    let Field    = RecordField.Contacts;
    
    record.addFieldValue(Field.FIRST_NAME, query.firstname);
    record.addFieldValue(Field.LAST_NAME,  query.lastname);
    ...
    record.addKeyValue(`Email`, query.email);
    
    // do stuff with record.

}
```

The issue is that the library in which the class above is defined only includes a bynch of standard fields. In reality my database has lots of custom fields added.

If I go into the node_packages, and add my extra stuff into the class Contacts, it will work. For example, if I add these:

```
// My Custom fields xxxx
    static APP_EMAIL = new Field("App_Email");
    static MOBILE_SESSIONS = new Field("Mobile_Sessions");
```

I can then successfully do this:

```
if (query.mobilesessions) { 
    record.addFieldValue(Field.MOBILE_SESSIONS, query.mobilesessions);
}
```

However, obviously, I can't just go in and start hacking about inside node modules! I've tried to extend the field in one of my modules to create a new extended field that I can work with instead, but I'm getting over my head.

```
const { SDK_API }       = require(`../../config`);
const ProductField      = require(`${SDK_API}/record/field`).Field;

// const RecordField          = require(`${SDK_API}/record/field`).Field;
// const ZCRMRecord           = require(`${SDK_API}/record/record`).MasterModel;

let Field = RecordField.Contacts;

class MyProductField extends ProductField.Contacts {
    static NUMBER_OF_GROUPS = new Field("Number_of_Groups");
}

module.exports = { MyProductField };
```

But I am getting the error : `Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: Field is not defined`. I'm getting confused by the apparent multiple field references... Unfortunately a min reproducable example would involve building a whole project, which is (at least for me) a lot of work. Hopefully the details provided are adequate to provide a theoretical answer, which I can verify.

Comment: "*`if((apiName != null) && (!(Object.prototype.toString.call(apiName) == "[object String]")))`*" - holy s**t, was that code autogenerated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, subclassing is not the answer here. For one, `RecordField.Contacts` probably shouldn't have been a `class` at all, the part you've shown us has only `static` fields which basically abuses the class as a simple namespace. So unless `new Contacts` is ever instantiated, you don't need to use anything like inheritance.

Also, you don't need to extend the `RecordField.Contacts` in any way. Those `new Field` instances do not need to be part of a namespace for being able to use them. Just define a few local constants in your code:

```
const { Field } = require(`${SDK_API}/record/field`);
const ZCRMRecord = require(`${SDK_API}/record/record`).MasterModel;
const builtinFields = Field.Contacts;

// My Custom fields
const customFields = {
    APP_EMAIL: new Field("App_Email"),
    MOBILE_SESSIONS: new Field("Mobile_Sessions"),
};

async function updateRecord(query) {

    const record = new ZCRMRecord();
    
    record.addFieldValue(builtinFields.FIRST_NAME, query.firstname);
    record.addFieldValue(builtinFields.LAST_NAME,  query.lastname);
    if (query.mobilesessions) { 
        record.addFieldValue(customFields.MOBILE_SESSIONS, query.mobilesessions);
    }
    ...
    record.addKeyValue(`Email`, query.email);
    
    // do stuff with record.
}
```